# ls command for searching specific files in current directory

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ls

How to use ls command for searching specific files in current directory. Let's say where file name contains "localhost".

Answer (score 2):

Take advantage of [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) for details. So try

```
ls *localhost*
```

If you want to search *recursively* in a directory for some file, use [find(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) (or, from some C program, the [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html) function).

Perhaps you want

```
find . -name '*localhost*' -exec ls {} +
```

Some shells, notably [zsh](http://zsh.org/), have recursive globbing. I am using `zsh` as my login shell, so I can type

```
ls **/*localhost*
```

BTW, you might be interested by [xargs(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) (very useful when combined with `find`). Of course, take time reading documentation of [ls(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html).